Ethers.js function calling error
I've made a simple getter function which returns a state variable's numeric value in the smart contract.
The following is the code I've written inside the App function:
function App(){
const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  const [newContract, setContract] = useState("");

  async function connect() {
    if (window.ethereum) {
      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
      const signer = provider.getSigner(0);

      const newContract1 = new ethers.Contract("0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3", abi, signer);
      setContract(newContract1);

    }
  }

  async function getValue() {
    try {
      const value = await newContract.getter();
      const num = value.toNumber();
      setValue(num);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    connect();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {value}
      <button onClick={getValue}>Get</button>
    </div>
  );
}

This is the error I'm getting :
Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="getter()", data="0x", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.7.0)
    at Logger.makeError (index.ts:269:1)
    at Logger.throwError (index.ts:281:1)
    at Interface.decodeFunctionResult (interface.ts:427:1)
    at Contract.<anonymous> (index.ts:400:1)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (index.ts:1:1)

I tried the above code 4 months ago which compiled perfectly on the latest version of ethers at the time(6.8.1 I think) while ran only on 5.7.2, but now it's not running on any of the versions

Which chain or network does your contract with the address 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3 belong to?
